# jquery animation in function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is called in a `onclick` in my `<img>` that calls.

```
function opengal(id){
    document.getElementById('gal_img').innerHTML="<img id='gal_active' src='" + imgs_array[id].source_t + "' />";
    gal_id = id;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        showId('gal');
        showId('gal_back');
        $('gal').fadeTo(3000, 1);
        $('gal_back').fadeTo(3000, 0.9);
        if (gal_id + 1 === imgs_array.length) {
            $('next').fadeTo(3000, 0);
            hideId('next');
            showId('prev');
            $('prev').fadeTo(3000, 1);
        } else if (gal_id === 0) {
            $('prev').fadeTo(3000, 0);
            hideId('prev');
            showId('next');
            $('next').fadeTo(3000, 1);
        } else {
            showId('prev');
            showId('next');
            $('next').fadeTo(3000, 1);
            $('prev').fadeTo(3000, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

The `showId` and `hideId` calles a `document.getElementById(id).style.visibility=""` to show the elements that are hidden for a slideshow-like gallery that is set above the rest of the page. after it shows these elements its suppose to change its opacity to fadeIn the element. The elements are being shown, but not the animation.

I think the cause is because the function is called outside the rest of my `$(document).ready()` as the imgs are generated in php for loop for displaying images from my database, with each image having its own id and calling its own `opengal(id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot to put the id selector in jquery,`#`, Change your code like,

```
$('#gal').fadeTo(3000, 1);
$('#gal_back').fadeTo(3000, 0.9);
```

If you want to refer the elements using class name, use `.`, Then your code will be

```
$('.gal').fadeTo(3000, 1);
$('.gal_back').fadeTo(3000, 0.9);
```

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot missing that. lol, funny how you miss the simple things.

Comment: I will prefer one more thing, you can directly use $('#gal').hide() and $('#gal').show() instead of calling a function